# How to store logs for every API call in a separate text file

Tags: karate

Using Karate i am making API calls sequentially. I need to store API request and response for this sequential flow of APIs in separate text files for each API call.
Need to understand how can i achieve this.

I have tried logback which stores entire execution logs in a text file.

Comment: I have marked it as Accepted. Could you please help with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`karate.prevRequest`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-prevrequest) which will give you the "request". Now use some custom Java (or JS) code and write whatever you want to a file.

I think personally it is un-necessary because Karate's HTML report has all that you need. If someone is asking you to do this, please try convince that person that this exercise is a waste of time.

Comment: Hi Peter. We wanted directly print the HttpClient response to a txt file.                         1 > POST https://api.obapi.bankofireland.com/oauth/as/token.oauth2
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
14:41:30.753 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 959
1 < 200
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < x-fapi-interaction-id: 824515e3-b850-4902-a0ad-ebb63fc9b58a
1 < x-frame-options: DENY
1 < x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
{
  "expires_in": 299
}

Comment: for those interested in other alternatives, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475